# How should I filter dates in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm creating a set of "archive" pages that are specified by year and month. In my table I have a `datetime` field called `posted`. I want to select all rows that are in a particular month.

I've thought of two solutions:

(1) Use string matching:

```
SELECT ... WHERE posted LIKE '2009-06%'
```

(2) Use some MySQL extraction functions:

```
SELECT ... WHERE YEAR(posted)=2009 AND MONTH(posted)=6
```

Which of these will be quicker, and are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT   *
WHERE    posted >= '2009-06-01'
         AND posted < '2009-07-01'
```

This one will efficiently use an index on `posted`, unlike both your queries.

Note that if your were keeping `posted` as a `VARCHAR`, then the following query:

```
SELECT ... WHERE posted LIKE '2009-06%'
```

would use the index too.

Comment: Wouldn't the BETWEEN operator be more appropriate here?

Comment: Hmm, I guess not, as you have to do CASTs in MySQL with BETWEEN on dates: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: @R.Bemrose: it would return the records that fall on '2009-07-01 00:00:00' exactly for both June and July queries. It can be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. For some reason it didn't occur to me that I could use < > selectors...

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding reservations about this design, the standard syntax would be "BETWEEN first-date AND last-date", or (if you're using less than date granularity), "posted >= first-date AND posted < last-date + 1".